# Is it possible to change the cache mechanism after creating a jhipster application

Tags: ehcache, jhipster, hazelcast

I have created a jhipster microservice project with ehcache enabled. Later i feel , to change the cache mechanism to Hazelcast from ehcache. Is it possible to do this, with the existing jhipster microservice application, without creating a new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit the `.yo-rc.json` file in your project, change the line `"hibernateCache": "ehcache"` to `"hibernateCache": "hazelcast"` and then run `jhipster --with-entities` to re-generate your project. Don't forget to commit all your changes before.

Comment: Thanks @Gael Marziou. I am curious to know, why all the changes are lost, whenever we regenerate/ recreate an entity !

Comment: Could you clarify which changes?

Comment: Changes we made in Domain, Service, ServiceImpl , Resource classes (Java)

Comment: If we add/ remove a field in an entity, all my custom codes located in Domain classes/ Service/ Service Impl has been removed. And i am getting a fresh code again

Comment: Yes if you added custom code in classes generated by JHipster it's your responsibility to use git to merge them.